# How to deploy server settings outlook 2016 office 365

Tags: group-policy, outlook, microsoft-office-365

How would i deploy the mail server settings for outlook 2016 connecting to office 365?

can this be completed via gpo?

Comment: What settings are you trying to configure?

Comment: Autodiscover should be handling this automatically, no?

Comment: when the user first runs outlook 2016, i want the mail server setting to be auto populated.

Comment: Can you explain which bit of autodiscover you're having trouble with?  What do the tools at exrca.com make of your autodiscover config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing you have Auto Discover configured (and the users SMTP address is correct in AD) you can enable the "*Automatically configure profile based on Active Directory Primary SMTP address*" Group Policy setting which will bypass the wizard and automatically configure the profile.